# nm program - why such name?

Tags: utilities, development, nm

Where does the name of `nm` come from? The [IEEE standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nm.html) defines `nm` as:

```
nm - write the name list of an object file
```

Is `nm` an abbreviated form of word `name`/`names`? Or does it have a completely different origin?

Comment: As you noted, it is the short form of *name list*.

Answer (score 2):

It's an abbreviation for "names" or "name list".

> Nm prints the name list (symbol table) of each object file in the argument list.

(V7 Unix manual, 1979)

from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858445/why-is-the-nm-utility-named-as-such

Answer (score 2):

early unix commands get a two letter code, often with wowel removed.

- list (files in dir) -> `ls`
- copy (files) -> `cp`
- link (files) -> `ln`
- remove (files) -> `rm`
- C Compiler -> `cc`

In this case, search for object name, this yield nm.